# How to get root access on Android in JNI code

Tags: java, c

I added some Java code to get root access, just create a new process and execute su command. But some of my JNI C code require root privilege. For example I called open("/dev/block/mmcblk0",O_RDONLY) and this require root access. But it still failed though I have root access. Why is that and how to fix that problem?

My Android device has been rooted and my app successfully gain root privilege.

I tried to gain root access through this way:

```
Process process=null;
        DataOutputStream os=null;
        try{
            process=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
            os=new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
            os.writeBytes(command+"\n");
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("###DEBUG###",e.getMessage());
            return false;
        } finally {
            try{
                if(os!=null){
                    os.close();
                }
                process.destroy();
            }catch(Exception e){

            }
        }
```

Comment: How is it failing? Are you seeing any error messages in dmesg or logcat when it fails?

Comment: no there isn't any message in dmesg. The open call returns -1

Comment: I use strerror to show the error message and it's permission denied. And my uid is 10111,why is that?